# HTTP requests from a nodejs instance running on GitHub actions gets a 401 error

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I am currently having a weird issue with GitHub actions. Basically I have a created a workflow that runs a nodejs app; that app makes on startup an HTTP request to the github APIs  using a personal access token, but for some unknown reason the request gets a 401 unhautorized error. The token is passed as an env variable using the github actions secrets, so when looking at the action's log you only see ***.
That app works absolutely fine when running on my PC, which makes it even weirder.
I have came up with two possible issues:

1. the token is not correctly passed to the nodejs app, but I can't verify it cause if I pass it as plain text GitHub deletes the token from my account
2. the GitHub APIs refuses HTTP requests from a GitHub action

I'll paste some code so you can get a better understanding.
Workflow:

```
steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      env: 
        MYTOKEN: ${{secrets.MYTOKEN}}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: sudo apt install -y git
    - run: npm install -g sass
    - run: npm ci
    - run: MYTOKEN=${{secrets.MYTOKEN}} npm run start
```

The axios' instance creation on nodejs:

```
const axios = require('axios').create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'Authorization': `token ${process.env.MYTOKEN}`}
});
```

And finally the error log:

```
/home/runner/work/Buildy/Buildy/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16
  var error = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (/home/runner/work/Buildy/Buildy/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/home/runner/work/Buildy/Buildy/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/runner/work/Buildy/Buildy/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  config: {
    
    [...]

    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      Authorization: 'token ***',  // <---- here you can see the censored token
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.26.1'
    },
    baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
    params: { per_page: 1, sha: 'master' },
    method: 'get',
    url: '/repos/filocava99/Fortress/commits',
    data: undefined
  },
```

Any idea on what might be causing the error would be very appreciated, thank you

EDIT: I managed to debug the env variable containing the token and it is actually passed to the nodejs app, which means that the issue might be the GitHub APIs refusing HTTP requests from a GitHub action

Answer (score 0):

Apparently everything is working fine now. Maybe the github server thought I was using the github actions with malicious intentions and temporarily denied all the requests.